# Active Record or SQL query for leaderboard (postgres rank and sum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rank

I am looking or help creating an advanced query in Rails/Active Record (or SQL using Postgres) for a contest.

I have a contest table, a users table and an activities table. Contests have many users (participants) and users have many activities. Each activity has points, a 'trackable_type', and other attributes.

What I want selected:
- first_name from the users table
- last_name from the users table
- a sum of the points for each user as total_contest_points
- a count of activities that have the type 'Course' for each user as total_contest_courses
- the results returned ranked by total_contest_points and then total_contest_courses

I have taken a look at the postgres_ext gem and tried writing sql, but I can't seem to get the ranking to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
time_range = start_time..end_time
contestants = participants.joins(:activities).where('activities.created_at' => time_range).select("
  users.id,
  users.first_name,
  users.last_name,
  sum(activities.points) as total_contest_points,
  sum(
    case
    when
      activities.trackable_type='Course'
    then
      1
    else
      0
    end
  ) as total_contest_courses,
  rank() OVER (ORDER BY total_contest_points DESC) as contest_rank
").group('users.id').limit(limit)
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered bypassing AR completely and going straight to `find_by_sql` or `select_rows`? ORMs generally aren't that great for this sort of thing.

Comment: I think raw sql would be best, but I'm still unsure how to write it, would you have a suggestion? Would I need to use multiple WITH statements?

Comment: You'd just unroll the `joins`, `where`, ... into SQL and throw the whole thing into a `find_by_sql` call. You'll run into problems with the `GROUP BY users.id` but you can fix that by adding the other two `users` columns to the GROUP BY.